# How to show a marker in camera preview

Tags: android, camera, augmented-reality, marker, arcore

I am an iOS developer, newbie to Android App Development. I am currently developing an App in Android where I have to open the camera preview and show a marker right in front. As the user pans through the camera, the marker should be fixed at one point and should be visible only when camera is pointed at that region.

I know this can be very easily done in iOS using the ARKit. (https://www.raywenderlich.com/172543/augmented-reality-and-arkit-tutorial)

I need some reference on how to implement this on Android. Should I be using ARCore or is it possible just using the Camera API and SurfaceView?

Thanks!

Comment: `marker should be fixed at one point`? AFAIK This can be done by AR only or you can try `OpenCV` (only if you have time to dive into it). ARCore is available on API 25 and later . If you want support lower versions your should check other libraries Some of them free some are paid . I have tried EasyAR once its quite great. you can give it a try.

Comment: @ADM oh ok. Are there any reference project that you can suggest?